# How to check if a JPasswordField is NOT empty?

Tags: java, swing, validation, jpasswordfield

what is the opposite of this code --> `password.getPassword().length == 0`

Like instead of empty you check if it is filled.

```java
JButton confirm = new JButton("Sign Up");
confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    UserInfo a = new UserInfo();

    /*here is my problem I want it to Check if someone inputted a password so I can 
                proceed to open the second frame */


    if(!firstname.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !lastname.getText().trim().isEmpty() &&  password.getPassword().length == 0 && pass2.getPassword().length == 0
        && !address.getText().trim().isEmpty() )
    
    a.frame2.setVisible(true);
    frame.dispose(); 
      
    
    if(firstname.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
      missingfirst.setText("Please Add Your First Name.");
  
    }
    if(lastname.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
      missinglast.setText("Please Add Your Last Name.");
    }
    if(password.getPassword().length == 0) {
      missingpass.setText("Please Add A Password.");
    }
    if(pass2.getPassword().length == 0) {
      missingrepass.setText("Please Re-Type Your Password.");
    }
    if(address.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
      missingadd.setText("Please Enter An Address.");
    }
    
    else if (!(password.getPassword().equals(pass2.getPassword()))) {
      missingrepass.setText("Password Doesn't Match.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: == in opposite is !=. but you should look into methods like: isEmpty() instead. myValue.trim().isEmpty(), for instance

Comment: Check using `password.getPassword().length > 0` or `!password.getPassword().isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

Check using `password.getPassword().length > 0` or `!password.getPassword().isEmpty()`.

I think here you should validate if the password entered is in correct format that you require rather than check if it is filled.